# Parse a Javascript File using Rhino

Tags: javascript, rhino

I have been assigned a task to read a javascript file using [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) and insert comments after every function like

```
input.js:
function f0() {
    var x = 10;
}
obj1 = {
    f1 : function() {
        var y = 30;
    },
    z : “z0”
}
```

and the output should be like

```
output.js:
function f0() {
     console.log('f0');
    var x = 10;
}
obj1 = {
    f1 : function() {
             console.log('f1');
         var y = 30;
    },
    z : “z0”
}
```

i can do it easily using java or c# but i have been asked to use Rhino specifically so any Rhino ninja out there who can guide me regarding using this interpreter for the said task

Regards

Comment: If, by doing it easily in java or c# you mean using regular expressions, then you can do the same in Rhino as JS also supports regular expressions.

Comment: @Ankur yup i can use regex.. i was hoping to utilize AST or some more sophisticated approach (if there is any) :) ... thanks...

Comment: Rhino does expose the parser API in the form of Parser class: http://mozilla.github.io/rhino/javadoc/org/mozilla/javascript/Parser.html.